# Failed Login with Tymon JWT Auth Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-8, tymon-jwt

When I try to get token with login function I get this error

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::login() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of App\Models\User given, called in ...\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTGuard.php on line 127 in file ...\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTGuard.php on line 140

Here my login function:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
```

Here my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    
}
```

How to solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement
`Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject` contract to your User model.

Comment: I had implemented it (I wrote my user model in my question) but it's still error

Comment: Nope. You make methods, but not `class User extends Authenticatable  implement JWTSubject `